# min heap in stl without comparator

Tags: c++, heap

I have just started using STL and was currently going through heaps.
I just wanted to know if there's a way to implement min heap in c++/cpp without comparator.

I tried the following code (a bit modification from geeksforgeeks) :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm> // for heap 
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // initializing vector;
    vector<int> vi = { 1, 6, 7, 9, 11, 4 };

    make_heap(vi.end(), vi.begin()); // swapped the start and end points

    cout << "The minimum element of heap is : ";
    cout << vi.front() << endl;

}
```

Output is : `1`

I tried this with other test cases as well and it seems to work fine. Just wanted to know if this is logically correct or not? Is it a good practice?

Comment: When you say "work", you mean you got a min heap? Besides, your check is flawed, the minimum element is already at the front. Your attempt could be doing nothing and you wouldn't know.

Comment: Yep., by work I mean they give me min heap. But you are right. My first element is the minimum itself. I checked. It gave an incorrect result. Thanks!

Comment: However, I am just curious if there's a way to make min heap without using a comparator.

Comment: @kancha, by "using a comparator", do you mean "having to wriite a comparator function?" (i.e., would using `std::greater` qualify as "using a comparator" in your mind?)

Comment: @Frank actually I don't have much experience with comparators. That's why I was trying a workaround without wanting to write the function explicitly. I am not familiar with `std::greater` . Just looked it up, I think it has same implemetation. We just don't have to write the whole function.

Comment: Both versions of `make_heap()` use a comparator.   The only difference is that the one which doesn't require a comparator as the third argument uses `operator<()` for the element type.    Swapping the iterators as you are would result in undefined behaviour, since `make_heap(a, b)` assumes it is allowed to access the element corresponding to `a` if `a != b`.   If `vi` has elements, `vi.begin()` and `vi.end()` are not equal, and `vi.end()` is "one past the end" so does not refer to an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your code:

```
make_heap(vi.end(), vi.begin());
```

This leads to **undefined behavior** because `vi.end()` is a past-the-end iterator. I.E. it does not point to an actual value, and dereferencing it would be illegal.

I think you were attempting to do the following:

```
make_heap(vi.rbegin(), vi.rend());
```

But that wouldn't have worked because the resulting heap would still have been a max_heap.

That being said, from the discussion in the comments, OP's question is actually "min heap in stl without **writing a** comparator", which is subtly different, and leads to a very different answer.

the STL provides ready-made templated comparators in order to handle these cases. The reasoning is that it's much cleaner to have fewer, more flexible algorithms. The lower the API surface, the better.

All you have to do is the following:

```
make_heap(vi.begin(), vi.end(), std::greater<>());
```